# java inetaddress isreachable not working

Tags: java, networking

I am trying to ping 200s of IPs in a loop in every 10 seconds. So, this loop gets executed in every 10 seconds. I was using this code to ping the IPs

```
for (i = 0; i <= 200; i++ )
{
   ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ping", isWindows? "-n" : "-c", "1", *SOMEIP*);
   Process proc = processBuilder.start();

   int returnVal = proc.waitFor();
}
```

This is just the part of my code. I am creating separate thread for every ping because if 100 IPs are down, then it will take more than 300 seconds to ping each & every IP sequentially. So, created separate threads. But the problem was that whenever the loop gets executed, then the PCs CPU usage reaches to 90%, which is not good for a critical system. So I change the program to this one.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 200; i++ )
{
   InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(*SOMEIP*);
   System.out.println(inet.isReachable(3000) ? "Host is reachable" : "Host is NOT reachable");

}
```

In the above code also, I am creating separate thread for each Ping because of the same problem. Now, here I am getting another problem. This code is giving unexpected result. The IPs which are pingable are also showing not reachable using above code. Why this is happening ?

Is the *isReachable* function buggy ?

I am using Windows OS.

Thanks

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: You should add the code that builds the IP under test. Also, I don't see how you can parallelize the check with such a loop. Finally, please dump a run of the program to some pastebin so we can guess the error

Comment: the only difference that I can think of is the program that actually executes the ping. in the first case you use ping.exe which is a windows executable while in the second it is either your IDE or the generated JAR. So an objective guess is that a firewall or a server configuration blocks all the requests in the second case. If so you have to add the IDE or the JAR to the firewall white list.

Comment: @Dien, I am using netbeans which creates Jar for both of the above codes. @Raffaele, I use this code for creating thread `Runnable r = new SendRequest(arguements); new Thread(r).start();` inside for loop above. In the SendRequest class, I wrote the ping code.

Answer (score 2):

Because they test different things, or rather they operate in different ways.

`ping` uses ICMP.

In practice `isReachable()` uses TCP.

Comment: You mean it is not possible with Java ?

Comment: I am answering your question why they yield different results and whether the `isReachable()` method is buggy. They use different parts of the IP suite and so are likely to encounter different firewall rules. I haven't said anything about 'not possible in Java'. I don't even know what you're now referring to as 'not possible'.

Comment: I mean in the first code, I am using Ping with the native windows ping command, which is creating the problem as I above explained. I am saying that is there not available pure Java way to check the network status in LAN ?

Comment: There is, and it's called `isReachable()`, but it works differently, as I have been explaining to you for a week. It would now be more to the point for you to describe what actual problem you are trying to solve. Why do you need to check 200 IP addresses, and what condition exactly do you need to check them for?

Comment: I just have a LAN with 150 to 200 Systems.I want to check if there is network fluctuation in any of the system connection. So, in every 10 second, I send a ping request to every 200 IP in the network to detect if there is any network failure occurred for any system because many times network fluctuation occurs in the network. So, just to detect in which System's network, the connection was failed.

Comment: I would suggest you get rid of the ten-second assumption, and the assumption that you can start 200 processes without saturating your CPU, and redesign your solution. For example, ping 20 IP addresses every second. Or every two seconds. Or ten per attempt. Or whatever doesn't overload your system yet meets your timeless requirements. Do you really need to know within ten seconds? And you certainly don't need to ping 127.0.0.1 at all. It's your local host.

Comment: Or execute `ping` *once*, to run continuously with the -t option, and .255 as the final part of the address, and parse the output, which will contain replies from every host in the subnet if they're working properly, and see which posts are missing for more than N iterations.